# Setting Image Button via it's id into a 8x8 2d array. Android. Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have made a 2d array of size 8 and 8 respectively, and i have made 64 image buttons, each with a b1, b2 b3 id. I would love to set the id into the array.

An example would be:

buttons[0, 0] = FindViewById(Resource.Id.b1);

buttons[0, 1] = FindViewById(Resource.Id.b2);
.

.

.

buttons[1, 0] = FindViewById(Resource.Id.b9);

Since I have 64 image button, do i have to write 64 lines to initialize each Resource.Id to be parsed into the 2d button array? I know I can do a double for loop for each row and column such as:

buttons[x, y] = FindViewById(Resource.Id.b1);

However I have to hardcode the resource.id of the image button to specify. Any way to shorten this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the ID of the button dynamicaly and fill your array:

```
    int overallCounter = 1;
    for (int i = 0 i < 8; i ++) {
       for (int j = 0;j < 8; j++ ) {
           buttons[i, j] = FindViewById(Resources.GetIdentifier("b" + overallCounter, "id", this.PackageName));
           overallCounter++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry... but Im not too good with android. What does this line of code does? And how is it supposed to help me substitute the 64 id into each data in array?

Comment: Thanks Taier. Sorry Im too used to using FindViewById to set the value into the array. Im trying to understand the code. For overrallCounter, I start at 1, and in the for loop, I will be getting the identifier, of b and the value 1, to become b1, and "id" is equivalent to Resource.ID?

Comment: @user3448790 yes, your right. After that loop will go to the next iteration and overallCounter will be 2, so it will get the second button and so on....

Comment: Alright thanks a lot :D You saved my life here haha!