# Xamarin IF statement to match image button and it's background

Tags: c#, android, image, visual-studio, xamarin

I am currently following up on this problem here: [Setting Image Button via it's id into a 8x8 2d array. Android. Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260761/setting-image-button-via-its-id-into-a-8x8-2d-array-android-xamarin).

I have successfully set the 64 image button's id into an 8x8 array. In my image button, there are some buttons with an image on the button with the following code:

```
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:background="@drawable/white"
```

There are other image buttons that are blank with no image. My question is: Of all my 64 image button, I would like to count how many buttons that has a background image white, based on the code I have above.

Currently I have the following code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //Rows of the array "buttons"
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) //Column of the array "buttons"
            {
                if(buttons[i, j] ==  ....???) //Check if the id of the image button has a white drawable image.
            }
        }
```

What should I input to finish up the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#.NET I try to put these kind of information in Tags. To use Tags in Android you have to create a String resource in values/Strings.xml. This is used to make sure, that the tag is unique.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="ColorOfButton">color</string>
  </resources>
```

When you initialize the buttons you can create a tag like so:

```
buttons[i, j].SetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton, "white");
//sets it to white
```

Or in XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/testBtn">
    <tag android:id="@string/ColorOfButton" android:value="white" />
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/testBtn2">
    <tag android:id="@string/ColorOfButton" android:value="black" />
</Button>
```

Then you can get the tag and look if it is white, black or empty:

```
switch(buttons[i, j].GetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton).ToString()) 
{
  case "white":
    //Your picture is white
  break;
  case "black":
    //Your picture is black
  break;
  case "empty":
    //Your picture is empty
  break;
}
```

You can put the following strings in your tag:

white - for white piece

black - for black piece

empty - for no piece

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. android:background="@drawable/white", this refers to a file in my Resources -> Drawable and it's named white.png. I am not referring to the color. I am referring to a file name.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the misunderstanding. I have edited my answer and tested it in VS2015.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Im sorry if my question wasn't elaborate. I am trying to make a Reversi-like game, and my current goal is to find out at any point in time, how many image buttons are filled with white pieces, and how many image buttons are filled with black image button. The thing now is... I have many 64 image buttons, since 64 pieces on the game board, each data stored in an 8x8 2d array. My goal, as I said, is to find the number of white pieces I have. My aim now is to check for every row/column if that image button in that array has a white.png in the background. How do I check?

Comment: An example would be right at the start, there are 2 white pieces and 2 black pieces located in the middle of the game board, so I want to run a loop, such that at array [0,0], since it is located at the top left side of the board, and there is no image, it will continue to move on [0,1], [0,2] etc until it reaches [3,3] and it is a white piece, and that my if statement can detect that in that image button, there is a white.png set as the background from Resources/Drawable in VS. I hope this clarify what I want to achieve. Because I don't really see how your solution can help my problem.

Comment: If you are reading the first sentence of this problem, I have created an 8x8 array size with each image button given a tag b1, b2 , b3 etc, and they are stored in the 2d array. So since the array is initialised as an Image Button array, i want to go through them one by one via. columns and rows to find out which image button has that background. I have tried: "if(buttons[i, j].Background = GetDrawable.white" in the double for loop as my closet attempt but to no avail.

Comment: So you initialize the image of the button in xml. You can do this with the tag too, as I found out (I add it to the answer). And for your game you have to change the picture, whenever a player sets a button to white. Then you can change the tag too.
I don't know any way to check the picture of a button, but with tags you can add this information. You just have to set it whenever the background is set / changed.

Comment: If you can't get the name of the picture of your Button or determine if ther is a picture at all you have to try another way. As I don't know how to get the image name, I can only show you how to do it in another way. With this approch you are no longer checking for images, but checking what is inside the tag to determine if it is white, black or empty.

Comment: That is a alternative Im considering. So if I am not mistaken, your solution is for me to add a tag, white or black to the predefined 4 Reversi pieces right at the start. and that everyone the user press an image button during their move, while add the image into the image button, I add the tag too into that particular array where the user pressed? and by checking the tag, instead of the image, to find out how many white/black pieces are there?

Comment: Also, "In Android you have to create a String resource in values/Strings.xml". Sorry if Im mistaken, since my main game board and design is located under GameLayout.axml. Am I supposed to create another xml file called Strings with just those <resources> data in it only?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. You can also add an "empty" to all the empty pieces, so you can use a switch: switch(buttons[i, j].GetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton).ToString()){ case "white": break; case "black": break; case "empty": break;}

Comment: The thing with android is, that you need a key to add a tag. This key is created in the resource files:  <resources> <string name="ColorOfButton">color</string> </resources>

Comment: In my project, there is a folder called values and in this folder there is a file called strings.xml, that should be created by default. If not, you can create it and the Build Action has to be set to AndroidResource.

Comment: Found it. Sorry for that stupidity questions. I have to be honest, I have barely heard of tags since I am a student in Android programming. I will see if your solution works. Implementing it now

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask when something is unclear. Wish there would be a chat function though.

Comment: Urgg damm. I got a : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I wanted to test the count of the amount of white piece, or tag in my program. Ran into that error. I have already added the extra <string name="ColorOfButton">color</string>. The line producing the error is the following : buttons[3, 3].SetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton, "white"); where I tried setting the array point [3,3] that has a white image background to assign it a tag. Can you help?

Comment: Try to check if buttons[3,3] is null. If this is the case you should check how you initialize your buttons.
do you intialize with: FindViewById<Button> ?

Comment: How do I check if button[3,3] is null? is there any windows or error messages icon that can aid me in this?

Comment: Is it okay if you are able to refer to the link right at the top of this question? I attempted to use the code there to assign each imagebutton (id b1, b2, b3... b64) to be added to a 8x8 arrays called buttons. After doing so, I have managed to set the tag:     buttons[3, 3].SetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton, "white"); The next thing is to do the double for loop to check for the tag, and the line producing the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error is the expression: if (buttons[i, j].GetTag(Resource.String.ColorOfButton).ToString() == "white")

Comment: In Visual Studio ther is something called "Direktfenster" in German. This opens when you debug. There you can execute code like buttons[3,3,] == null
Or you can write this in your code and save it into a bool an check it

Comment: I can't see a reason why you can set it, but not get it, if the buttons object is the same and not newly created. I have to go for today and we have to find another way to comunicate, i think the comments are not made for this.

Comment: Hi. That was apparently my error, missing out an id due to a type. All is well and Im working on the logic for Reversi. Thanks a lot, your solution really helped me!

Comment: @AeneasMotsch worth earned reputation